# Parallel Transport Equations

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, spherical-geometry, gradient-flows

I have a question about parallel transport that I'm very confused about and would appreciate some help. The question reads:

> What vector field $X$ on the unit 2-sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ has rotations around the $z$-axis as flows? The orbits of these flows would be the lines of latitude. Solve the parallel transport equations $\nabla_X(V_i)=0$, for $V_1, V_2$ the elements of a basis of the tangent plane, along the curve of latitude 45 degrees. What do the $V_i$ come back to once one has transported them all the way around the circle?

I am confused by which vector field the question is talking about. Would this field just be the sphere parametrized as:

$$(x,y,z) = (r\cos(\theta)\sin(\varphi), r\sin(\theta)\sin(\varphi), r\cos(\varphi))$$
Where $\varphi$ is constant?

Comment: The curves $\varphi=\text{constant}$ are the lines of latitude to which they refer. But you want the *vector field* everywhere tangent to those. When you work with the sphere, parametrized as you did in spherical coordinates, what are the natural choices for $V_1$ and $V_2$?

Comment: ... I'm not quite sure, maybe something to do with stereographic projection?

Comment: Yikes, way too hard. Just differentiate the parametrization with respect to the independent variables! (You'll find all this in my text you've already looked at, of course.) :)

Comment: I'm just gonna throw my textbook out and replace it with yours! Thanks once again @TedShifrin!

Comment: I'm confused by the $X$ vector field. The $V_1, V_2$ are the (sphere denoted by $S$) derivatives $S_{\varphi}, S_{\theta}$ respectively. But what would $X$ be?

Comment: Above, by an abuse of notation, $$S_{\theta}=\frac{\partial S}{\partial\theta}, S_{\varphi} = \frac{\partial S}{\partial\varphi}$$

Comment: Well, rotating about the $z$-axis means that we're varying $\theta$, fixing $\phi$, so it must be $S_\theta$ :) Remember that to do the parallel transport around a closed curve, you want to fix a starting (and ending) point and see how the vector field turns when you return to the starting point after one trip around.

Comment: I computed $\nabla_{S_{\theta}}(S_{\varphi})=0, \>\>\nabla_{S_{\theta}}(S_{\theta})=0$, but I'm confused by what it means to transport it along the curve of 45 degrees?

Comment: They mean to set $\varphi = \pi/4$, but your computation is not correct.  $S_\theta$ definitely does *not* have covariant derivative $0$ along $\varphi=\pi/4$. ... And there are pictures of this exact thing, and a good deal of discussion and derivations, in my text ... :P

Comment: So I'm confused by the question... Why does it say solve $\nabla_X(V_i)=0$ when the parallel transport equation does not give 0?

Comment: Because the problem is badly stated. They want you to solve that for a vector field $\tilde V_i$ with $\tilde V_i(p) = V_i(p)$ for your starting point $p$. Again, look at my example(s) on this.

Comment: I believe it is Example 3 on page 68 you are referring to?

Comment: Yes, Felicio. See also the remark on p. 71 for an intuitive discussion of this phenomenon. Probably reading and working through the section carefully would be helpful.

Answer (score 14):

This isn't a direct answer to your question about the parallel transport equations, but the standard geometric solution. Assuming a unit sphere, parallel transport around the latitude $L_{\varphi}$ making angle $\varphi$ with the equator can be found by constructing the cone tangent to the sphere along $L_{\varphi}$, then cutting the cone along a generator, rolling it flat, and performing parallel transport of a tangent vector around an arc of a circle.

Elementary geometry shows that the unrolled cone is a sector of a disk of radius $\cot\varphi$ whose central angle is $2\pi\sin\varphi$. Parallel transport around $L_{\varphi}$ in the northern hemisphere rotates a vector clockwise (looking "down" at the tangent plane, toward the center of the sphere) by an angle $2\pi\sin\varphi$. The animation is a full-circle pan around the sphere.

[image: Parallel transport on the sphere]

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for this great way to think intuitively about parallel transport on a sphere. I had been confusing me for ages why the vector needs to turn.

Answer (score 0):

For points on the equator.  you may find all elipsoids that are present on the north hemisphere exert the same integral sum of vector acceleration around a regular surface.  their transport should be similar to a circle transport at the equator.  it is the case that a transport with some location       a (t)i that the integral sum of acceleration is greater than the distance around the world at the equator so it is not similar.

Comment: a (t) i must be below the equator for some t,i